# How "this" work within a _.each loop? / how do you call on a return from a _.each loop?

Tags: angular, angular-material, lodash

I'm trying to create a modal using Angular Material and I'm having a hard time getting my data to display. The error that I am getting is that it can not find listOfPaths of undefined. It looks like adding "this" within the nested _.each loop created this problem. I'm confused on what is happening and would like guidance.

here is my code:

in data.component.ts

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'app-data',
  templateUrl: './data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data.component.css']
})
export class DataComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() data;

  listOfPaths = [];

  private resourcesLoaded: boolean;

  constructor(private router: Router,
              public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ViewComponent, {
      width: '1650px',
      data: this.data

    });

  }
}
```

in view.component.ts

```
    import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-view',
  templateUrl: './view.component.html',
})

export class ViewComponent implements OnInit {

  listOfPaths = [];

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ViewComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
      this.getPathsAsList();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

  getPathsAsList() {

    this.listOfPaths= [];

  _.each(this.data.network, function(path){
    _.each(path.fileTypes, function(fileType){
       this.listOfPaths.concat(fileType.modifiedPaths);
      });
  });

  }

}
```

in view.component.html

```
    <ol>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let path of listOfPaths">
      <li>
        <p>{{path}}</p>
    </li>
    </ng-container>
  </ol>
```

Comment: Try changing your `function`s to arrow functions. Like this: `(path) => {...`. Same thing with the function that has the `fileType` parameter.

Comment: @R.Richards  when I tried doing that, it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You are loosing context when passing function as a callback. And `concat` does not mutate initial array, so you'll have to use `push` or reassign `this.listOfPaths` value.

You need to either change **both** functions to be arrow functions.

```
  _.each(this.data.network, (path) => {
    _.each(path.fileTypes, (fileType) => {
       this.listOfPaths = this.listOfPath.concat(fileType.modifiedPaths);
      });
  });
```

Or capture array in closure

```
var listOfPaths = this.listOfPaths = [];

_.each(this.data.network, function(path){
    _.each(path.fileTypes, function(fileType){
       listOfPaths.push.apply(listOfPaths, fileType.modifiedPaths);
      });
  });
```

Also you don't really need lodash for this. Arrays have [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method that allows to pass a context as the third argument.

Comment: thank-you Yury Tarabanko for your help, the modal is displaying correctly now!